# What is Windows command to convert machine name to ip address and vice versa?

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, lan, ip-address

I need to know the ip address of another machine in a lan network.

What is the Windows command for getting ip address from machine name and vice versa?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

A machine with machine name **"accounting"** and ip **"192.168.1.95"**

**IP -> Machine Name:**

```
tracert 192.168.1.95
```

or

```
NBTSTAT  -a 192.168.1.95
```

**Machine Name -> IP**

```
nslookup accounting
```

or

```
ping accounting
```

Comment: `ping -a` can also be used to convert IP to hostname

Answer (score 18):

in window 7 and later versions. 
to find ipv4 ip by hostname you can try following methods.

For ipv4 (192.168.1.2):

```
ping hostname -4
```

For ipv6 (0000:0000:0000:0000:0000):

```
ping hostname -6
```